# Get out of Maze

Tags: algorithm

The maze is in the form of a rectangle with n rows and m columns. Each cell of the maze is a room and a room in the ith row and jth column is addressed as room(i,j). Rows are numbered from 1 to n from bottom to top and columns are numbered from 1 to m from left to right.

The maze has two types of rooms: type A and type B. In each room of type A, there is a monster who is very hungry and We must give him a candy. The room also contains one gold coin. In each room of type B, there is a guard who is very greedy and we must give him a gold coin. The room also contains a candy.

Every room has a door to every adjacent room (Rooms that share an edge are adjacent rooms). Before entering the maze We has a choice of taking either a gold coin or a candy. If person enters the maze from room(1,1) and he has to reach the room(n,m) to get out of the maze. We need the minimum number of rooms he needs to visit to get out of the maze .If it is not possible then also return -1

EXAMPLE: Say maze is 3*3 that means N=3 and M=3

and let 0-type A room and 1-type B room then

0 1 1

0 0 1

0 0 0

To get out of maze one has to pass through 5 rooms in minimum.

Comment: Good, good. And what is the question?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i need to tell minimum number of rooms if he can reach to (n,m) room

Comment: @LeviStanley I am thinking of doing a dfs by making a graph but I think their can be a pretty simpler way than it

Comment: any time or parameters constraint?

Comment: @emcas88 N and M ARE upto 1000

Comment: You need to use a breadth-first search, not a depth-first search.  Everything you need to know to solve this is covered in chapter 3 of *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* (and in many other books).

Comment: And pretty much in any kind of planning related resource

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code in C++, any doubt you can ask me, i used a BFS and tested some cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>

static const int MAX = 1000;

//this matrix store the current minimum value (0,0) ----> (i,j)
static int maze[MAX][MAX];
//original value matrix
static bool flagMatrix[MAX][MAX];
//matrix used to mark visited nodes in the bfs
static bool marked[MAX][MAX];

using namespace std;

int dx[4] = { -1, +1, -0, +0};
int dy[4] = { +0, +0, -1, +1};

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;

    point(int x1, int y1) {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
};

//this function check if the point is inside the bounds of the maze matrix
bool inRange(struct point p, int n, int m) {
    return 0 <= p.x && p.x < n && 0 <= p.y && p.y < m;
}

int main()
{
    int xn, ym;

    scanf("%d %d",&xn,&ym);

    for (int i = 0; i < ym; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < xn; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&flagMatrix[j][i]);
            maze[j][i] = MAX + 1;
        }

    maze[0][0] = 1;
    queue<struct point> q;

    point init(0,0);
    q.push(init);

    //BFS
    while(!q.empty()) {

        point current = q.front();
        marked[current.x][current.y] = true;
        q.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            point children(current.x + dx[i],current.y + dy[i]);

            if(inRange(children,xn,ym) && !marked[children.x][children.y] && flagMatrix[current.x][current.y] != flagMatrix[children.x][children.y]) {
                //here is the key condition
                maze[children.x][children.y] = min(maze[children.x][children.y],maze[current.x][current.y] + 1);
                q.push(children);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", maze[xn - 1][ym - 1] == MAX + 1 ? -1 : maze[xn - 1][ym - 1]);

    return 0;
}
```